# index.html page loads (Angular 2 RC-7) but Cannot match any routes: '' in console

Tags: angular

First I am building my frontend and setting up a few pages to route to each other than I will hook up spring-boot in for the backend.

However my index page loads, but I get the following error in my console.

`core.umd.js:5995 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''`

routes.config.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path:'home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
    //{ path: '**', component: Error404Page }
   // {path: '/register', name:'Register', component: Register},
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Current only the login page is ready, here is the component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl:'./login.html'
})

export class LoginComponent {

    login:LoginModel = new LoginModel();

    constructor(public loginService:LoginService){
        console.log("Inside constructor...")
    }

    onSubmit() {

    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, routing],

    declarations: [AppComponent,
        LoginComponent, HomeComponent,NavigationBar],

    providers:[LoginService, appRoutingProviders],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

I read Angular's latest tutorials and it appears I am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set **default route** which is not there in your routing,

**NOTE** : *not sure but useAsDefault is removed but still need to confirm it from someone*

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [ 

{path:'',redirectTo:'home', pathMatch: 'full'}, //<<<===here 
{path:'home', component: HomeComponent}, 
{path:'login', component: LoginComponent}, 

];
```

Also make sure **AppComponent** has `<router-outlet>` somewhere in HTML.

Comment: When I do the above I get the following `EXCEPTION: Invalid configuration of route '': redirectTo and component cannot be used together`

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Now it just says `Cannot find primary outlet to load 'LoginComponent'` but the main page still renders. When I click on the link it just refreshes the page.

Comment: what do you want to achieve tell me when you run your app?

Comment: To click on the Navigation bar or any link and it go to that page. Once I have that I will work on the services and spring-boot.

Comment: I'm asking you when you run your app, which route you expect as a default route? (I feel first route should be home)... how does login component come into play?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124238/discussion-between-drew1208-and-micronyks).